# Resource Not Found Exception with ContextCompact

Tags: android, colors, resources

I'm facing the following the exception with the below code snippet. Tried all the possible solutions found in SO. But not helping me to fix this problem.

This logic is crashing while passing zero. Zero need to pass when all the cases are failed in Switch case.

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, 0))






android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

Comment: Why are you passing 0? That's not a valid resource ID. That method is expecting an `R.color`. I would also mention that you generally don't want to get color resources from the `applicationContext`.

Comment: I have to pass 0 if all the cases are missed;

Comment: Why, though? Which color are you expecting to get back from that? Are you trying to set a plain color value there, like just black? You wouldn't use the `ContextCompat.getColor()` method, in that case. You would pass the value directly to `setTextColor()` instead.

Comment: I will receive some status from server; if status is not matches with case then we have to remove background

Comment: Hi @MikeM. I have my edited my comments above please help us.

Comment: So you're just trying to set it to transparent? Then it would just be `setTextColor(0)` (or `setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)`). You don't use `ContextCompat.getColor()` for actual color values. (I'm not really sure if you mean to set the text color there, or the background color.)